# Change size of text in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, text-size

```
final Button btmins = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btmins);

btmins.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View t){
        float n = textfield.getTextSize();
        textfield.setTextSize(n--); 
    }
});
```

This my try to change the size of EditText, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you put `--n` instead of `n--`?

Comment: @donfuxx Simply awesome, thumbs up! :)

Answer (score -1):

The increment and decrement operator can only be used for integers, not for floats.
Try to make the change procentual. I would try this Code (not tested):

```
textfield.setTextSize( 0.8 * n) ;
```

Comment: textfield.setTextSize(n-1) ;